# String truncates earlier than it should be

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an onclick javascript method with dynamic content as:

```
onclick="adviceEvent('${advice?.content}');"
```

advice content has somewhere in between string like:

```
Check these details carefully - you don't want to miss a offer because you h...
```

due to apostrophe in **don't**  firbug says:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

How can I resolve this.Any thoughts?

Comment: can't you escape the apostrophe by using ``\`` likewise it will be `you don\'t want to miss a...`

Comment: is it possible to add a jsfiddle in your question so that we get the exact scenario to investigate

Answer (score 1):

if its possible you need to create a code that will escape apostrophe before it will be executed by the browser so change the

```
onclick="adviceEvent('${advice?.content}');"
```

into

```
var str1 = '${advice?.content}'.replace("'","\\'");

onclick="adviceEvent('"+str1+"');"
```

I think using another extra variable will do just to get away with all the confusion between escaping quotes within the codes itself.

Comment: This replace('\'','\\') seems not workibg as firebug still complaints the same.

Answer (score 0):

you should escape the `'` on the server side

Do something like-

```
onclick="adviceEvent('${yourDynamicContent.replaceAll("'","\\'")}');"//your server side code to replace all '
```

**replace all `'` inside your `dynamic content` on server side not on client side**

As on the client side if your `dynamic content` contains any of `'` then on the client, it will be turns into some invalid javascript String.

Lets say your dynamic content prints `hi'hello`,
then on client side your code will be

```
onclick="adviceEvent('hi'hello');"//'hi'hello'  a invalid string in js
```

but if u escape `'` from your dynamic content
the this will be like

```
onclick="adviceEvent('hi\'hello');"//'hi\'hello' a valid string in js
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys for your Answers But, I resolved My issues By just swapping the position of single and double quotes:

```
onclick="adviceEvent('${advice?.content}');"
```

to

```
onclick='adviceEvent("${advice?.content}");'
```

mind the position of quotes.

and all perfect.